# Change HTTPNotFound renderer using pyramid_handlers

Tags: python, pyramid

I guess the title speaks for itself.

I've been searching on how to change the page that shows up when a 404 happens on my server. All I've seen so far was chaging it using Hooks as the documentation says.

It turns out I'm using pyramid_handlers and I have no idea how to change it.
Would anyone be kind enough to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyramid.view import notfound_view_config

@notfound_view_config(renderer='404.html')
def not_found(request):
    return {}
```

Comment: so I just need to create my views.py again?